# Consider the following map:

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

$T:(C^1[0,1],||.||_u)\to\ (C[0,1],||.||_u)$

$T(f)=f'$

it is obvious that T is a linear operator.since$(cf)'=cf'$.
Consider $f_n(t)=t^n, t \in [0,1]$

Here,$||t^n|| \le1$. Also $||f_n||=1,\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thus $||T(f_n)||=||T(t^n)||=||nt^{n-1}||=n$ which is not bounded.
But why $T: (C^1[0,1],|||.|||)\to\ (C[0,1],||.||_u)$ is bounded?

($T(f)=f'$ and $|||.|||=||f||_u+||f'||_u$)

Comment: Are you really using the same norm on both spaces? If then $T$ is taking the derivative the answer should be pretty obvious -- by bounding the $C^0$ you have no control over the $C^0$ norm of the derivative. Just look at the sequence $f_n(x) = x^n $ on $[0,1]$. (assuming that this is the $C^0$ norm. Which you should also explain).

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the edited question separately, because it is a different question. Editing the question so much makes the people who answered it look like fools. Anyways I answered the new question also.

Comment: very very Thank you for answer.... sorry...I typed wrong....This is My question ... can you help me?....

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f_n(t)=t^n, t \in [0,1]$

Here, $||t^n|| \le1$. Also $||f_n||=1,\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

But, $||T(f_n)||=||T(t^n)||=||nt^{n-1}||=n$ which is not bounded.

Now, for  $T: (C^1[0,1],|||.|||)\to\ (C[0,1],||.||_u)$ you get

$||T(f)||_u = ||f'||_u \le ||f||_u+||f'||_u= |||f||| \implies ||T|| \le 1$. Hence this $T$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about differentiation operator, consider 
$$f_n=x^n\in C^1[0,1],\,n=1,2,3\cdots$$
Using the usual sup norm, then $|f_n|\equiv 1$ but
$$|Tf_n|=|nx^{n-1}|=n$$
which is obviously unbounded.